# Ruby rack app on 1 CPU - how many processes should I run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, rack

I'm quite new to Ruby web apps (coming from java). 
I have VPS that has 1 CPU and 2GB of RAM and would like to play with some rails/sinatra stuff.

I'm using Ruby 2.1.0 MRI
How does number of CPUs maps to number of web server's processes I need to run? I use puma as a web server and have default threads (0,16) set up. But I noticed there is also "workers" option that forks another process to better handle multiple requests.

Do I understand correctly that for such setup (1 CPU) there is no point in running 2 web server processes? The only reasonable setup is 1 process with threads?

Answer (score 3):

Oh now this is a pretty big question!

The number of processes and threads aren't necessarily linked to the number of CPU's.  It's more a case of the amount of memory available, the amount of concurrent requests and the amount of 'locking' stuff that's going on.

If you're going to have long running requests that block other requests, then having additional processes can help with that.  You can still have more than one process with a single CPU.

There are a number of different servers in Ruby that handle scaling in different ways, Unicorn, Puma, Thin are some of them.  Doing a search on Unicorn vs Puma vs Thin can turn up some useful blog posts on the topic.

Here's a couple

http://ylan.segal-family.com/blog/2012/08/20/better-performance-on-heroku-thins-vs-unicorn-vs-puma/
https://www.engineyard.com/articles/rails-server
https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1822610

And some information on concurrency in Ruby
http://merbist.com/2011/02/22/concurrency-in-ruby-explained/

The TL:DR answer is, it depends!

Comment: Thanks. For the last few days I've read several articles/comparisons etc. I don't fully get this thing with number of processes. I read on Puma website:

"On a ruby implementation that offers native threads, you should tune this number to match the number of cores available."

So I understand that if I have 1 CPU there is no point in forking new process. Am I right?

Comment: Also if I understand correctly the thing is if I have IO operations (DB read, file read, external API call) ruby switches threads and lets other thread do its work when one is waiting for IO. So it looks like typical web app should be fine with only 1 worker (process) but with some threads inside (eg. Puma with 16 threads). Or do I miss something?

Comment: Here's another article about performance http://blog.wiemann.name/rails-server
The problem with anything to do with concurrency is that there are no real easy answers.  The article explains a strategy for 'testing' concurrent request, but at the end of the day you really need to adjust to your individual use case under load.  What might work for one app many slow another to a crawl.

Comment: In relation to the the DB component, again, it depends!  There are things that can be done to improve this using more DB connections.  See here for more info - http://blog.codeship.io/2013/10/16/unleash-the-puma-on-heroku.html